# Optimize MethodInfo.Invoke when method info is only known at runtime

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, invoke

I am using reflection to call methods, and invoking the methods using Invoke() doesn't do it for me, too slow. I generate thousands - millions of method calls, it is a test automation tool. At compile time I have no clue about the method name, parameter type(s) or return type. So Jon Skeet's article on [using delegates to cache reflection](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx)  is no help here.
Here is what I have:

```
foreach (MethodInfo method in _methods)
{
    foreach (var p in method.GetParameters())
    {
        var paramValue = Utils.RandomizeParamValue(p.ParameterType.Name);
        parameters.Add(paramValue);
    }
    var result = method.Invoke(_objectInstance, parameters.ToArray());
    //_objectInstance is the class instance of which the method is a member of.
}
```

I have researched the DLR (ExpandoObject, DynamicObject) but I am not sure it has what I am looking for. What I am looking for is a way to bypass the overhead of reflection, or cache method invocations, even if it turns out be an ugly hack. Is there a common hack that I have missed? Could I go down to IL level and do some tricks there?

Comment: It can be done with light code generation (probably the same approach as John's article - the site's down for me right now), but it's not a walk in the park. You have the MethodInfo which specifies all the args and return types, you need only to generate a method call (via expressions or IL generation). At least with IL, you create a dynamic method thne you need to load on the stack the object instance then passed args (can't remember how right now) then issue a an OpCodes.CallVirt with the MethodInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use expression tree to build delegate that will call your methods. MSDN have introduction in [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) article and in particular you'll need [MethodCallExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.aspx)

Create an expression sample (from `MethodCallExpression` article):

```
string[,] gradeArray =  
    { {"chemistry", "history", "mathematics"}, {"78", "61", "82"} };
var  arrayExpression = Expression.Constant(gradeArray);

// Create a MethodCallExpression that represents indexing 
// into the two-dimensional array 'gradeArray' at (0, 2). 
// Executing the expression would return "mathematics".
var  methodCallExpression = Expression.ArrayIndex(
    arrayExpression,
    Expression.Constant(0),
    Expression.Constant(2));
```

`Compile` an expression to delegate sample (from main article):

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = num => num < 5;
Func<int, bool> result = expr.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(result(4));
```

Comment: I could also take a look at what the new Roslyn release can do for me in terms of reflection